# Tips for XML performance optimization on WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7

I have an application on the phone and it takes in about 50 pages of XML, each XML has about 100 nods in it. So if you do the math that is about 5000 nodes I am parsing. Sometimes these nodes are not set up the same. Example: maybe 75% have a different schema than the other 25% so there is code to handle this and parse them differently.

I can't optimize the http calls any more then I have as the web services only serve up data 100 "items" at a time, so I have to hit the web service 50 times basically to get all the pages of data. Here is the high level process.

```
Call web service (webclient)
Parse XML (take note total pages in xml. it will say Page 1 of 100)
Add results to collection 
Call web service again for page 2 
Parse
Add results to collection 
....rinse and repeat 100 times.
```

The parsing code is really the only place I can optimize. All I am doing is using linq to parse the XML and separate out the nodes in an IEnumerable and then I parse them and place them in a custom object I created. I'm looking for some high level ideas on how to optimize this entire process. Maybe I'm missing something.

Some code....just imagine the below, just like 1000 times or more, and with more attributes, this is a small example. Most have like 30 attributes that need parsing..Also I have no access to a real schema, and no control over schema changes.

```
XElement eventData = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
IEnumerable<XElement> feed =
    (eventData.Element("results").Elements("event").Select(el => el)).Distinct();
foreach (XElement el in feed)
{
    _brokenItem = el.ToString();
    thisFeeditem.InternalGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    thisFeeditem.ServiceIcon = GetServiceIcon(thisFeeditem.ServiceType);
    thisFeeditem.Description = el.Attribute("displayName").Value;
    thisFeeditem.EventURL = el.Attribute("uri").Value;
    thisFeeditem.Guid = el.Attribute("id").Value;
    thisFeeditem.Latitude = el.Element("venue").Attribute("lat").Value;
    thisFeeditem.Longitude = el.Element("venue").Attribute("lng").Value;
}
```

Comment: Two questions come to mind off the top: (1) is the XML that you get from the service different each time this is invoked, or are there time when nothing changes and (2) do you have any control whatsoever over the service's behavior?

Comment: code sample of your parsing would be helpful.

Comment: I will add some code when I get home but to answer a question. I have no control over the service. I would prefer a giant single XML over a paged version. I have a feeling the API was designed for paging web pages, not a fat client. Secondly, the results are different on every page.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, it is not easy to optimise it. However, there is one general point you should consider:

Linq-to-XML is a DOM-based parser, in that it reads the entire XML document into a model which resides in memory. All queries are executed against the DOM. For large documents, constructing the DOM can be memory and CPU intensive. Also, your Linq-to-XML queries, if written inefficiently can navigate the same tree nodes multiple times.

As an alternative, consider using a serial parser like [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Parsers of this type do not create a memory-based model of your document, and operate in a forward-only manner, forcing you to read each element just once.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the architecture.

Create a web service that does the collection and filtering of the XML data and on the phone retrieve the data from that web service.

This way you move the heavy processing to a (scale-able?!) server and you only have to modify the service when the XML sources change instead of having to update all clients.

You can also cache results and prevent duplicates.

Now you are in full control of what happens on the phone.

Comment: This is on the distant horizon right now, I'm working on an Azure version of the code so the phone just makes a call and waits for the answer in a single chunk (compressed maybe). I think an azure server will deal with the xml quick and perhaps deal with caching better.