# out of memory exception while parsing xml @ wp7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

i'm creating an app to read twitter feeds, but, sh*t happens. OutOfMemory Exception happens while parsing it.

so, here is the code of the parser:

```
MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel();
mvm.Items.Clear();

if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
{
    XDocument xTweets = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
    foreach (var tweets in xTweets.Descendants("status"))
    {
       ItemViewModel ivm2 = new ItemViewModel()
       {
           TweetImage = tweets.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
           TweetSender = tweets.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value,
           Tweet = tweets.Element("text").Value,
       };
      Items.Add(ivm2);
    }
}
```

so, which line's making the trouble? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An OutOfMemroyException indicates that your application has run out of memory. This cannot be attributed to any single line of code in your application! How big is the XML file you are parsing?

If it is large, you should consider using  using a serial parser like [XmlReader][1]. Parsers of this type do not create a memory-based model of your document, and operate in a forward-only manner, forcing you to read each element just once.

See this related question:

[Tips for XML performance optimization on WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152801/tips-for-xml-performance-optimization-on-wp7/9156338#9156338)

Comment: The xml file I'm parsing is a twitter feed which is small